# Can Project Tango help users navigate through a physical space for which no ADF has been created?

Tags: accessibility, oracle-adf, google-project-tango

I would like to explore using Project Tango to help guide blind or low vision users through a physical space.  One of my main questions, is whether an Project Tango must have an existing Area Definition File first in order to reasonably accurately give the user about the space.

Answer (score 1):

Yes -  the ADF is what Tango uses to correct for drift errors - theoretically you can do area learning on the fly but I've always had problems saving off the file

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Actually, the features you looking for in tango is related with Motion Tracking. or you can also add depth features on top of it. 
Please check the Concepts explaining in below:

https://developers.google.com/project-tango/overview/motion-tracking
https://developers.google.com/project-tango/overview/depth-perception

Answer (score 0):

You should learn the environment using an ADF if precise recognition of certain locations is important. Have a look at my demo here where I'm using a learned ADF. You can clearly see how the ADF corrects the locations (performs relocalization) when the perimeter is 'jumping': https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMbNykdPDRo

Run this Google SDK example to get the ADF tracking running. Actually, all you need is adding the ADF name and some additional frame pair to the Tango config and then waiting for the relocalization event in function 'onPoseAvailable':
https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-java/blob/master/java_basic_examples/hello_area_description/src/main/java/com/projecttango/examples/java/helloareadescription/HelloAreaDescriptionActivity.java